# How do I manually uninstall PIL from OSX (snow leopard)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, python-imaging-library, uninstallation

I managed to manually install PIL on my macbook (without package managers, please don't answer use xcode, as I want to do this manually).

Unwanted answers:

- just install xcode/pillow/[use pip](http://pastebin.com/kx7BM7wy)/etc

The answer I am looking for could be:

- a python script that will do that in your system can be found here
- use these terminal commands
- less good: the files PIL installed are here, here and here, delete them

I used these commands amongst others:

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

And I got this result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      darwin 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49)
              [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.
```

My big picture problem (which I will address in another question) is that I need FREETYPE2 support, but the first step will be to uninstall PIL correctly using either a python script or the terminal. My system has an intel processor and is OSX version 10.6.8

Thanks

Comment: Did you install this for Apple's pre-installed Python 2.6, or a different Python installation?

Comment: Meanwhile, hopefully you now understand why you should have done `pip install pillow`, and why you should do so after you remove the old version, so you never have to do this again. :)

Comment: Hold on… the only reason you don't want to use pip is that it says you already have the requirement up-to-date? Have you tried passing `--force-reinstall`?

Comment: @abamert python is 2.6. When I use pip I start down a rabbit hole of errors which would warrant its own separate series of questions. Your answer seemed to work fine for my system so I accepted it :). I have further probs with pil (re freetype support) but lets address that in another question and not make it messy here as I got a good answer ^_^

Comment: I know Python is 2.6; that's obvious from the output. What I asked is whether it's Apple's pre-installed Python 2.6 or a different one.

Comment: @abarnert it was the osx pre-install. My directories were the same as the defaults you listed in your answer. BTW, I just found that after uninstalling pil, I tried re-installing and something (I know not what) I did in the last few days had fixed freetype2 support :D Just needed that uninstall and that was it. Thank you again ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple script you can run that will do this in all cases. (That's a large part of the reason `pip` was invented…)

---

Apple's pre-installed Python 2.6 sets its default site-packages directory to:

```
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

… and its scripts directory to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

So, `sudo python setup.py install` will install everything to those two directories.

If you're using a third-party Python, or have changed the configuration, the locations may be elsewhere, so I'll refer to these as ${sitedir} and ${bindir} below.

Exactly what you get installed depends on which version of PIL or pillow you installed. With the last few versions of PIL, it should be:

- ${sitedir}/PIL
- ${sitedir}/PIL-x.y.z-py2.6.egg-info
- ${bindir}/pil*.py (five scripts)

Depending on the way you have `setuptools` and/or `distribute` installed, you may not have the `egg-info` directory. With Pillow, the egg-info file is named `Pillow-x.y.z-py2.6.egg-info`. With older PIL, you may have only four scripts instead of five.

Anyway, if you have the `egg-info` directory, look at the `installed-files.txt` inside of it. All of those files, relative to the `egg-info` directory itself, are what got installed. However, just passing that file to `rm -rf` will leave behind any directories automatically created along the way—most notably, the `${sitedir}/PIL` package directory. You *could* write a script that removes each file, then removes any directories that are left empty as a result… but that could be a bad idea if, e.g., you happen to have nothing else in `/usr/local/bin`. So, it's useful as a guide to drive or double-check manual cleanup, but it won't make everything automatic.